# Is there a way to solve this problem - sum of powers

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving, exponential-sum

$N_1^a + N_2^a + \ldots + N_n^a$
Where a is any number.

Example
$40^7+ 37^7 + 35^7 + 32^7 + ... 1^n=R$

If Iknow what $R$ is and that $ N_n$ is restricted to $0 \lt N_n \le 40$, Is there a way to find the $N_n$'s values used?

Comment: I think your sum is not correct.

Comment: The data does not necessarily determine the $N_i$, e.g. the "taxi cab number" $1729=10^3+9^3=1^3+12^3$.